# How to create instance of models with circular and null=False relations?

Tags: django, django-models

I have models with circular relations and I wanted also have null=False on them. Example below.
All this is nice, but how do I create the objects in this case?

```
class Data(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey('Master', related_name='data', null=False)


class Master(model.Model):
    last = models.OneToOneField('Data', null=False, related_name='+')
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do? A `Master` object can have many related `Data` objects but also has a reference to a "last" `Data`?

Comment: by default `null=False`, but I am a little bit confuse with your models, the fact that Data model has a ForeignKey to a the Model Master, and this latter has a OneToOne to Data...

Comment: I am trying to keep track of the latest Data (it will be getting read many time over), without having anything added to Data that gives order. All Data per Master is a rarely read set, mostly for historical references. Best analogy would be a Person and all of his/hers addresses, where one is the current.

Comment: you can always `.order_by('id')` - cuz `id` is default field and it exists in every model and it gives an order. Take the last one `id` here, to get the "latest Data".

Comment: @David R. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use *"circular"* relation. You use `reverse ForeignKey` relation to reach your model. Also you have to change your models:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey('Master', related_name='datas', null=False)
    anotherfield = <some_field>

class Master(model.Model):
    last = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

filtering_masters = Master.objects.filter(datas__anotherfield = "some_value").select_related('data')
```

If you need to get last row from `Data` you can use:

```
last = Master.objects.select_related('data').filter(last = "some_master_name").order_by('-datas__id')[0]
```

**NOTE:** there is `__` (double underscores) here - `datas__id`.

Comment: @Lemayzeur but he said he need just `latest` Data? I guess this is just 1 last row? Adding DateTime to that model is not required in that case, I think. But sure, it is better :) But he also said he doesn't want adding anything else to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to `Data` that keeps track of the last updated time (or last added time). Then use this field to query for "last"

```
class Data(models.Model):

    master = models.ForeignKey('Master', related_name='data')
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now you can query the "last" bit of data like so

[latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#latest)

```
master_obj.data.latest('added')
master_obj.data.latest('updated')
```